# Именованные возвращаемые значения и naked return

Tags: golang, инспекция-кода

В golang есть `naked return` и именованные возвращаемые значения. Зачем их придумали?

```
func c() (i int) {
    return
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предположим, у меня функция на экран или больше. Тогда оказывается неудобным читать её без наличия возвращаемых переменных.

```
func c() (i int) {
    return
}
```

Если в коде функции возвращаемая переменная могла меняться, тогда становится некомфортно читать код. Следить за этим всем сложно.

Я её всегда старательно избегаю. Но часто вижу, как другие разработчики её используют. Несколько раз мне говорили, что используют эту конструкцию для сокращения кода. Только такой аргумент выглядит не очень разумным. Да и кода сокращается немного, а читаемость (опять же на мой взгляд) сильно падает.

При этом, следует отметить, что подход с именованными переменными хорош, так как позволяет указать, что за переменная возвращается. Подходу `naked return` он не противоречит:

```
func c() (i int) {
    return i
}
```

Данный подход может использоваться для `[go code review comments][1]`.

В [некоторых](https://coderoad.ru/48680222/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE#48683488) случаях без `named error` не обойтись, но по-прежнему не ясно назначение `naked return`:

```
func noMorePanics() (err error) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            err = r.(error)
        }
    }()

    potentiallyPanickingFunction()
}
```

Но с использованием именованных возвращаемых значений следует быть крайне аккуратным, так как могут быть сайд-эффекты, которые сильно затрудняют чтение кода:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    f := fmt.Println
    f(a())
    f(b())
}

func a() int {
    i := 0
    defer func() {
        i += 1
        fmt.Println("a defer : ", i)
    }()

    return i
}

func b() (i int) {
    i = 0

    defer func() {
        i += 1
        fmt.Println("b defer : ", i)
    }()
    return i
}
```

Обращайте внимание на использование замыканий. Это может быть коварно. Во втором случае вернётся 1. А в первом 0. Это связано областью видимости и не интуитивно. `i` определяется внутри или снаружи функции. Но как мы видели выше, может быть полезно в специальных случаях. И быть выстрелом в ногу -- в других.

Comment: За такие неявные сайдэффекты, как в вашей функции `b`, нужно бить канделябром по голове, ИМХО. Я за явное обновление значений в теле функции, а не постфактум в `defer`.

Comment: @PakUula прочтите ответ на вопрос. Я также критикую такой подход. Но иногда он неизбежен. Опять же, прочтите ответ

Answer (score 0):

Я бы разделял именованные возвращаемые значения и `return` без значений.

Первая фича очень полезна, когда возвращаются больше одного значения. Имена служат документацией, особенно если несколько возвращаемых значений одного типа:

`func Divmod64(numerator, denominator int64) (quotient, remainder int64) { ... }`

Сразу понятно, где тут частное, а где остаток.

Named values return - это логическое продолжение идеи переменных для возвращаемых значений. Если мы их уже объявили в сингнатуре функции и присвоили в теле функции, то зачем повторно указывать в `return`-е?

Несмотря на то, что такой `return` позволяет сэкономить несколько символов при печати на клавиатуре, я предпочитаю всегда указывать, что именно я возвращаю. Однажды я потратил полдня на поиск ошибки, вызванной таким неявным возвратом значений. Больше не хочу. Целее буду :)